# Text replacement on different lines

Tags: python, regex, awk

I have multiple entries in a file as mentioned below.

```
 "Item_1";"Item_1";"Products///Item///ABC///XYZ";"Item_1.jpg}";"";"Buy item
 <br><strong>Items</strong>
 <br><strong>Time</strong>";"";"";"";"";"";"Category: M[Item]";"";"";"Y";"N";"N";"None";""

 "Item_2";....
```

In above text, there is a newline after "Buy item" in the first line & after '/strong>' in second line.

The change which I want to make is -

```
1. Replace Products///Item///ABC///XYZ with Products///ABC///XYZ
2. Replace "Category: M[Item]" with "Category: M[ABC]"
3. In case if Entry 1 is Products///Item///ABC or Products///ABC, I dont want to change "Category: M[Item]" with "Category: M[ABC]", just change Products///Item///ABC to Products///ABC
```

I am trying to read entire file line by line & then split by '///' storing number of entries & storing 3rd entry. But this creates issues as I have multiple newlines.

Is there a simpler way of doing it by using regex or something else?

Comment: use the csv module: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 2):

Like @Casimir suggested, you can use `csv` module to parse your file (because it'll handle the newlines), like this

```
import csv

with open(your_filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimeter=';', quotechar='"')

rows = list(reader)
```

and then do what you want to the parsed result (I'm not quite sure about what you want to achieve here, comment if that's not what you want)

```
for row in rows:
    if 'Products///Item///ABC///XY' in row:
        index = row.index('Products///Item///ABC///XY')
        row[index] = 'Products///ABC///XYZ'
        continue # If we replaced the first thing, skip to next row
    elif 'Category: M[Item]' in row:
        index = row.index('Category: M[Item]')
        row[index] = 'Category: M[ABC]'
```

Comment: Further it sounds like @AFH either needs to remember what was found for the 'Products///.....' line and use it for later lines in the CSV or they may need to read all of the CSV, process it, and write out if they really need more complicated logic.

Comment: Let's wait for him to clear this up. Also, he might not need help on how to deal with data anyway, just how to parse files with newlines (that's how I understood him).

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

I was able to change the parameters as needed using csv module. I have only one hurdle now, I want '"' enclosing each row element but I am just getting row with delimiter without quotes. I tried 

cw = csv.writer(open("File", "wb"), delimiter=';' , quotechar='"')
cw.writerow(row)

Where I am wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other problems with this? If not, consider accepting the answer, if it helped you:)